# How to create horizontal bar chart using react-chartjs-2?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create below given bar chart image using react-chartjs-2  But unable to do that and also tried with concept of stacked bar chart but nothing worked out. If anyone know this. Please let me know

Here is image for reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nptki.png

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HorizontalBar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const dataHorBar = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: "grey",
      borderColor: "grey",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70]
    }
  ]
};

const options = {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        id: "yAxis1",
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 11,
          fontColor: "black"
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
        }
      }
    ],
    xAxes: [
      {
        stacked: false,
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 7,
          fontColor: "black",
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HorizontalBar data={dataHorBar} options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this one help https://reactchartjs.github.io/react-chartjs-2/#/horizontal-bar

Comment: how to add grey colour for each bar ?

Comment: @kritiverma It's in the docs and in the source, see: https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/charts/HorizontalBar.js

Comment: @Thimma tried that one but facing problem regarding grey after maroon colour for each bar

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox or some source codr

Comment: @Thimma  Code added...Can you look into this again?